# GStreamer logs "Buffer has no PTS" when use omxh264enc and mp4mux in the same pipeline

Tags: gstreamer, openmax

I am trying to encode h264 stream with `omxh264enc` and mux it to mp4 container with `mp4mux` on Lichee Pi, TH1520.

Here is the example pipeline:

```bash
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=test_h264.mp4 ! decodebin \
  ! rawvideoparse use-sink-caps=true \
  ! omxh264enc ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=t_h264.mp4
```

But GStreamer logs such error:

```
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstMP4Mux:mp4mux0: Could not multiplex stream.
Additional debug info:
../gst/isomp4/gstqtmux.c(5410): gst_qt_mux_add_buffer (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstMP4Mux:mp4mux0:
Buffer has no PTS.
```

Changing `mp4mux` to `qtmux` logs the same error. I tired to set properties of every element in the pipeline but failed.

Answer (score 0):

This question is silimar to [gstreamer mux raw h264 to mp4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56973305/).

According to [Raspberry Pi Forum](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=206714) and [freedesktop GitLab](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-omx/-/issues/13), it seems that the requirements for `qtmux` on timestamp has been changed since GStreamer 1.10.x, while `h264parse` and `qtmux` didn't fulfill those requirements. `h264parse` has been [fixed](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-bad/-/issues/47). But gst-omx is long dead and has been [retired](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/-/merge_requests/4976/), maybe it is not profitable to modify the source code.

My solution is to use `avenc_mp4` instead.

```bash
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=test_h264.mp4 ! decodebin \
  ! rawvideoparse use-sink-caps=true \
  ! omxh264enc ! h264parse ! avenc_mp4 ! filesink location=t_h264.mp4
```

But `avenc` is not recommended to use from GStreamer manual, and it cannot mux h265 or vp9 (`matroskamux` doesn't support gst-omx as well). I would be appreciated if anyone provides a better solution to fix gst-omx directly.